# How to send TMS email to specific author who sends translation job?

Tags: web8.5, translation-manager

We have requirement to send TMS email notification to author on completion of translation job as well as intermediate retrieval of translation. We want email to be sent from TMS to author who sends job for translation. Currently, in TMS, we have email broker stage which sends email to author group but not to specific author.

I have following questions on above requirement:

how I can send author email id to TMS as part of translation job from Tridion?

In TMS, how can I have that email field available as part of translation job metadata so that TMS email broker program will read that field and send email to that particular email id?

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution would be to add the email address as an metadata field to your translation job and pass it to TMS. Please see the following documentation on how to add metadata to a translation job,

[Adding metadata information to Translation Jobs](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-8722AF3C-696F-4909-9A0F-198235EC2EAB#docid=GUID-DD563DCE-A639-494B-994D-D3012514C852&filename=GUID-DD563DCE-A639-494B-994D-D3012514C852.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-DD563DCE-A639-494B-994D-D3012514C852)

Comment: As documentation says, I created metadata schema in localized publication from where we send job for translation. I added meta data schema in translation configuration file. When I sent job for translation then I am getting below error:

Comment: "Two or more translation metadata schemas configured for the same blueprint (root publication id tcm:0-82-1). Only one translation metadata schema can be used per blueprint. (Conflicting schemas are tcm:282-142587-8, tcm:282-142587-8) ". I created schema only for Spanish publication still it is showing me that error. I am not understanding that document says "Create metadata schema per blueprint hierarchy". Currently we have structure to create metadata schema globally which is referred in all child publication.